# Is there a function to only assign properties on a destination if the property exists?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

This might be a pipe dream, but I'd love a JavaScript (or lodash?) function that does this:

```
let obj1 = {
  prop1: 'first thing',
  prop2: 'second thing'
};
let obj2 = {
  prop2: 'overridden second thing',
  prop3: 'and another thing'
};

let result = magicalFunction(obj1, obj2);

// result is { prop1: 'first thing', prop2: 'overridden second thing' }
```

In other words, I need a version of [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) that allows me to specify that I want one object's properties to be the "precedent," and that all properties on the source object(s) that do not occur on the precedent should be ignored.

Comment: `const magicalFunction  = (obj1, obj2) => {
for (const k of Object.keys(obj1)) {
 if (k in obj2) {
  obj1[k] = obj2[k];
 }
}
return obj1;
}` --- it literally is 3 lines of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it - iterate over `Object.keys` of the source object, and check if there is a property with the same name on the replacer object - replace if there is, and don't if there isn't:

```js
let obj1 = {
  prop1: 'first thing',
  prop2: 'second thing'
};
let obj2 = {
  prop2: 'overridden second thing',
  prop3: 'and another thing'
};

let result = magicalFunction(obj1, obj2);

function magicalFunction(source, replacer) {
  let output = {};
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => output[key] = replacer[key] || source[key]);
  return output;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Try `let obj2 = {
      prop2: ''
    }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's `_.pick()` and `_.keys()` (or `Object.keys()`) to take from 2nd object just the keys that exist in the 1st object. You can merge the original object with the picked keys using object spread:

```js
const magicalFunction = (a, b) => ({ ...a, ..._.pick(b, _.keys(a)) });

const obj1 = {
  prop1: 'first thing',
  prop2: 'second thing'
};
const obj2 = {
  prop2: 'overridden second thing',
  prop3: 'and another thing'
};

const result = magicalFunction(obj1, obj2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm accepting Jack Bashford's answer because it was a bit earlier than yours and, though I did say lodash was OK, his is all native JS. This is a very elegant solution, though!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function magicalFunction (obj1, obj2) {
    let keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
    let keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

    for(let i=0; i<keys2.length; i++) {
        if(keys1.indexOf(keys2[i]) > -1) {
            obj1[keys2[i]] = obj2[keys2[i]];
        }
    }
return obj1;
}
```

This function iterates over keys of both objects and overrides the value if a key in obj2 is also found in obj1.

Hope it is what you're looking for.